# How to get xcode derived data path

Tags: xcode

Is there a way I can retrieve through some bash command the path to the Xcode DerivedData folder?

usually it is something like

```
/Users/ThisGuy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

and I can replace it with

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

but this doesn't guarantee that the path to the derived data location is actually this one (the user may have changed it to a relative or a custom one)

Comment: `echo ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` ?

Comment: @vadian You can set up a custom Derived Data path.

Comment: @vadian How to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could get the value for key `IDECustomDerivedDataLocation` from user defaults.

```
defaults read com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist IDECustomDerivedDataLocation
```

If the line returns

> The domain/default pair of (com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist, IDECustomDerivedDataLocation) does not exist

it's the default path `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` otherwise the custom path.

Answer (score 5):

Hi you need to open xCode preferences from menu and follow the following instructions:
[image: To open derived data location]